# Django - Image post processing on save

Tags: django

If I want to be able to "post process" an image after it is uploaded, crop it down to size and apply some compression. As it stands, I am doing this using the post_save signal, when the model is saved, I am accessing the file, applying the post production and saving over the original.

I am only doing this when the created argument of the post save signal is set to true to avoid unnecessary image processing every time the model is updated.

**The problem**

When the image field of an existing instance is updated, the post processing of the image is being skipped because the created flag is false.

How can I setup my model to only apply post processing to the image when the ImageField has changed, even if the model is already created? **This app may not always be used with django admin**, so overwriting the imagefield_save method isn't going to work.

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

This question is from a long time ago, so probably not actual anymore?

did you have a look at:

```
pre_save.connect(before_mymodel_save, sender=MyModel)
```

have a look at [the signal documentation of django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/)

you create a function before_mymodel_save and you can try to do anything in there. If you're using a save inside the post or pre save functions: Just make sure you disconnect the signal if you save the MyModel object within this function (and connect again), to avoid endless loops.